# How to include javax package with Gradle

Tags: java, android

How can I add the `javax` package to my Android project with Gradle?
I have no idea where to even look for the link to that package.

Basically I am trying to get the script package from `javax` to my Android project.

Currently I am trying to do something like this: `compile group: 'javax.script', name: 'javax.script-api'`

But Gradle is unable to find that package for me.

Comment: "How can I add the javax package to my Android project with Gradle?" -- generally, you can't. Android's build tools do not support adding classes in the `java` and `javax` packages from the JDK into Android apps.

Comment: But I was able to add different stuff like `compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'` So why not script package too.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your **build.gradle** file

```
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
```